# Match statement with input versus without

Tags: pattern-matching

I'm trying to explain the discrepancy between the output of the following scenarios:

```
http_status = input("Please enter http status code: ")
print(http_status)
match http_status:
    case 200 | 201:
        print("200")
    case _:
        print("203")
```

This prints 201 then 203 when I enter 201 in the console.

```
http_status = 201
print(http_status)
match http_status:
    case 200 | 201:
        print("200")
    case _:
        print("203")
```

This prints 201 then 200.

First I confirmed `input()` works by printing `http_status` after I assign 201 to it. Then I confirmed the match statement works by confirming I get a "200" when I assign 201 to `http_status`. Given this, I can't explain why it's outputting 203 in the first code block.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the discrepancy is `input()` parses any input into a string. If I want the top result to be consistent with the bottom result, I need to do

`http_status = int(input("Please enter http status code: "))`